# Neccessary to call add_submenu_page and add_menu_page from admin_menu hook?

Tags: hooks, admin-menu

From the fm:

> NOTE: If you're running into the "You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page." message in a wp_die() screen, then you've hooked too early. The hook you should use is admin_menu.

I am able to create menu items and submenus from hooks much earlier than admin_menu eg: plugins_loaded.  In fact, it seems to work without any hook, at all, straight outta functions.php.  WP 4.0.1.  So, what gives? Is this old info?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how are you ending up with these results. The earliest hook it should work at is roughly `admin_init`. Anything as early as load process (`wp-settings.php`, including `function.php`, `plugins_loaded`, and even `init`) should (and does in my installation) produce fatal error, because function definitions hadn't loaded yet.

The definition for these functions (`wp-admin/includes/plugin.php`) are only loaded after bulkd of core load (`wp-load.php`) is done.

In a nutshell documentation *is* correct and it's a mystery why it works in your case. It shouldn't, short of exotically customized core load process.

Comment: plugin.php seems to load before functions.php.  I'm running a child theme of ET's Harmony theme.  But just an unadulterated wp setup.

Comment: Oh wierd... I tried it on another site, also child of Harmony theme, Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_menu_page() in C:blah/blah\www\wp-content\themes\Harmony_child\functions.php on line 24

Comment: auth_redirect seems to be the earliest you can hook.  Arrg, so I have no idea why the other site works.

Comment: Ahh... Redux framework includes plugin.php